# How can I change this data set to show the population as a percentage of the population?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, dataset, choropleth

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlKzD.png)

Since the data in the the choropleth map grows very high for some countries, I want to display the cumulative cases of covid as a percentage of population instead of the total amount of people in the country who have covid.

I can't find any data sets that do this, is there a way in python to execute this? I would like to use percentage of population as it would be of greater use because currently when a big country is at 30million cases you are un able to tell (from its color) if a smaller country has 100k cases or a 1-5 million cases.

code below

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv")

fig = px.choropleth(df, 
                    locations="Country", 
                    color_continuous_scale="Reds",
                    locationmode="country names",
                    color="Cumulative_cases",
                    width=1000,
                    height=900,
                    animation_frame="Date_reported",
                    title="Cumulative Cases by Country"
                    
                  
                   )
fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['frame']['duration'] = 30
fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['transition']['duration'] = 5

fig.show()
```

Comment: You would have to get the population size (since it's not in the dataset) and divide by that.

Comment: [Here](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL) is the data for 2021-2022; 2023 is not yet finished and will be difficult to get.